# how to install libdb4.8 on jessie?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt

since jessie has libdb5.3 which is incompatible with libdb4.8 how to install the latter. I added `oldstable main contrib ...` to the mirrordirector but no chance in finding it.

Where are the old packages located alias what to add to sources.list to get it apt found and install it libdb4.8 and libdb4.8++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are trying to get the old `libdb4.8` from a previous Raspbian version with *oldstable* version in `/etc/apt/sources.list` But this doesn't help much because you are really very outdated with your installation. You are using *raspbian-jessie* that is already *oldstable*. If you want to address the predecessor of jessie you must use *oldoldstable*, that is *wheezy*. You can also look at `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/` if you find `libdb4.8` in one of the older Raspbian versions.

Btw. a simple search with **libdb4.8** on google give me over 30,000 matches and just the first one from ubuntu shows where to get the library dev files:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get install -y libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
> ```

Maybe you will find also the library there. If not, then there are 30,000 other links.

And yes, you should really consider to upgrade your software to latest stable versions.